# How to capture the requested url and pass its substring to some other link in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http

I am making some changes in .htacess file and i want to capture the requested url, create substring of it and pass it to third part url.
For example

I am working on ubuntu, so currently my .htaccess file is in folder test. So when i access `localhost/test/http://www.facebook.com` , it takes me to `service.prerender.io/test/http://www.facebook.com` but i want to eliminate the 'test' and forwrd the request like `service.prerender.io/http://www.facebook.com`

Here is the code of my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/script.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://service.prerender.io%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` to set capture groups and instead of rewriting to `http://service.prerender.io%{REQUEST_URI}` you can rewrite to something like this `http://service.prerender.io/%1`.

Here is an example (untested):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/script.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?test/([.]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://service.prerender.io/%1? [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: still no luck, i tried your code with the same request i.e `localhost/test/http://www.facebook.com` but it took me to `service.prender.io/m` . I don't know how it is happening

Comment: not yet working, now it says url not found it doesn't load anything ERROR:404.

Comment: @Utkarsh I edited you can give it another try if you want.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to captures is not directly the requested uri but part of it. You can get it from rewrite rule

Try following

```
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ http://service.prerender.io/$1? [L,QSA]
```

If you're accessing a page something like,

```
https://www.example.com/thisdir/thisfile.php
```

Then you will get following as request uri and script uri

```
REQUEST_URI: /thisdir/thisfile.php

SCRIPT_URI: https://www.example.com/thisdir/thisfile.php
```

And https://github.com/prerender/prerender-apache is more information about htaccess and prerender